# Easy way to stage template updates for a live site

Tags: templating

Im curious if folks have found an easy way to stage template updates for a craft site thats already live.

Locally we have branch in the repo for the new version which works fine but on the server if we want to share them with the client ideally wed just use stage.sitedomain.com or something

Right now we are replicating the whole craft setup in a different location for a sub-domain and just sharing the database, is there a way to share a craft folder and just have a different templates folder?

Eventually looking to move some of this to vagrant cloud for staging environments but not quite there yet

Answer (score 1):

There is a PHP Constant [CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/php-constants#craft-templates-path) which you can use to specify your Template Path. Would that help you out any?

If you look at the top of the page linked above, it explains where you set the Constants.

Comment: ahh yes, that does help.  Do you think i also need a copy of storage or is ok to share a storage folder?  Seems to work either way but not sure if there are unintended consequences?

Comment: To be honest I've never done it. I guess if it were me, I'd air on the side of caution and keep them separate :)